# Does the AND operator in MyBatis test expressions short-circuit during evaluation?

Tags: java, mybatis

Is the AND keyword in test expressions in MyBatis implemented using a short-circuit? For example, I have written the following:

```
<when test="pagingInstruction != null
            and pagingInstruction.direction.toString() == 'FORWARD'">
...
</when>
```

If the first operand resolves to false, will the second operand be ignored? (I'm using MyBatis v3.0.4.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it is not stated in the reference doc that the test attribute of the *when* element short circuits, the reference doc includes an example that only works if the test attribute of the *when* element short circuits.

The example is similar to yours; here it is:

```
... stuff
<when test="author != null and author.name != null">
```

The easiest way to resolve your question might be to create some simple unit tests to determine how myBatis treats the "and".

Also, you may need to test that `pageInstruction.direction` is not null before calling `pageInstruction.direction.toString()`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That example had occurred to me just before you answered. :o)